# How to show the correct child "div" using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you help me with this issue, 
I have two dependent dropdown that hide and show divs based on users input.

Div 1 working fine, but Div 2 every time the user select, the Div 1 is affected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#YES').hide();
  $('#yestip').hide(5);
  $("#select5").change(function() {
    $('#YES')[this.value > 1 ? 'show' : 'hide']('slow');
  });

  $("#tip").change(function() {
    $('#yestip').hide('slow');
    $("#" + this.value).show('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
No. of sites:
<select name="sites" id="select5" required="yes">
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>

<div id="YES">
  Name:
  <input type="text">
</div>

<br>
<br>Yes or No:
<select id="tip" name="tip_scrub">
  <option value='NO'>NO</option>
  <option value='YES'>YES</option>
</select>

<div id="yestip">
  Total:
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#YES').hide();
    $('#yestip').hide(5);
    $("#select5").change(function () {
        $('#YES')[this.value > 1 ? 'show' : 'hide']('slow');
    });

    $("#tip").change(function(){
        $('#yestip')[this.value == 'YES' ? 'show' : 'hide']('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: wow, thanks for this BabL86.. but 1 question tho, hwat seems to be the problem in my previous codes?

Comment: @khangkhungkhernitz you are using this line $("#" + this.value).show('slow'); which will be like $("#YES").show('slow'); when you select yes in second select field, that effecting the first div with id "YES".